# My GitHub link shows only readme not my webpage

Tags: github

I published a repo in GitHub but if I click on the link it shows only readme content and not my webpage.
https://shrykos011.github.io/shrykos011coursera.github.io/index.html this is link of published page.
Below is my GitHub repo link
https://github.com/shrykos011/shrykos011coursera.github.io.git
Please someone help me.

Comment: https://shrykos011.github.io/shrykos011coursera.github.io/coursera.html try renaming this file index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you run a website and visit it on its root folder, the server will be looking for an index.html file. In your case, you see everything blank as you don't have that file.

To fix this, just rename your file to index.html and you should be able to run your website.